Service to write files with specific group and permissions C#
I am writing a program, intending to run it using the daemon/service/no-login user aaa.
User aaa is part of group shareabc and sharedef.
The configuration file for this program will look like:
{
   ... other config ...
   "locations": [
      {
         "id": "workflow1",
         "location": "/shr/abc",
         "group": "shareabc"
      },
      {
         "id": "workflow2",
         "location": "/shr/def",
         "group": "sharedef"
      },
   ],
   ... other config ...
}


/shr/abc belongs to root:shareabc
/shr/def belongs to root:sharedef

If, in my program, I call Directory.CreateDirectory("/shr/abc/myfolder1");, then /shr/abc/myfolder1 will be created with the owner aaa:aaa.
What C# code do I need to make it create the folder with the owner aaa:shareabc instead of aaa:aaa?
Running the program as user aaa group shareabc isn't a solution, as:

There are some files which should be aaa:aaa, and there are others which should be aaa:shareabc.  Changing the running user/group, or changing filesystem defaults, just shifts the problem rather than solving it.
I would run into the same problem when it tries to write to folder /shr/def using owner aaa:sharedef.


As for setting the permissions, it seems they've updated the C# API a few years ago.  I can just call the following to create it with 775:
Directory.CreateDirectory("/shr/abc/myfolder1", UnixFileMode.UserRead | UnixFileMode.UserWrite | UnixFileMode.UserExecute | UnixFileMode.GroupRead | UnixFileMode.GroupWrite | UnixFileMode.GroupExecute | UnixFileMode.OtherRead | UnixFileMode.OtherExecute);

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44623/250752 ?

That link doesn't seem to answer my question.  How do I specify user aaa:shareabc  when I am doing Directory.CreateDirectory("folder1");  If I do Directory.CreateDirectory("folder1"); I get folder1 belonging to aaa:aaa instead of aaa:shareabc.  aaa is a member of shareabc.  The link you posted is about when aaa is NOT a member of shareabc, which is irrelevant to my case.

Both chown and chmod require the write permission of the parent folder. If you don't have permissions to run them in one folder, you aren't even able to create any files or folders in that folder. Vice versa. And I think the question belongs to [unix.se], it really has nothing to do with C#.

Perhaps an alternative would be put aaa in sudoers, but limited to running a custom program that can only operate on a specific set of folders either in general, or depending on the user running it, that makes these changes to the file/folder the user desires. Just make sure you sanitise any input like a directory starting with ../ so that they don't escape the confines of the folders they're allowed to operate in.

@shingo You can assume the service user aaa has all relevant permissions (aaa is group member of shareabc and parent folder is root:shareabc, 775).  The question is when the service running under user aaa wants to create files and folders, what C# code is used to specify it wants to use aaa:shareabc, 775/664 instead of aaa:aaa 700 which would result from calling Directory.CreateDirectory("folder1").  I don't want to run the process using su -g shareabc <my program>.

@ProgrammingLlama None of that complexity is necessary.  I just want to run my app as aaa, not shareabc.  aaa is a member of shareabc, so should be able to write files as aaa:shareabc.  I just need to know the C# code to actually write as aaa:shareabc instead of aaa:aaa.  I know I could run the service as aaa:shareabc, but don't want to do that, as in a different parent location, it may be using a different group sharedef, so running the process as aaa:shareabc would mean I need to host multiple of this service, one for each group.

Since there are no permission issues, you can directly run the chown command.
Process.Start("chown", $"aaa:shareabc {directoryPath}").WaitForExit();

If you prefer a C# method, there are several packages Mono.Posix.NETStandard, Mono.Posix, Mono.Unix that do the work.
using Mono.Unix;
UnixFileSystemInfo.GetFileSystemEntry(directoryPath)
                  .SetOwner("abc", "shareabc");

This method actually calls the chown function of libc, so you can also do:
[DllImport("libc", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int chown(string path, int owner, int group);

chown(directoryPath, -1, group_id_of_shareabc);


Is there any way to define it before or while creating rather than create then fix after?  I was hoping for a solution similar to that which is available on Windows.  i.e. (linux equivalent of windows only C# code): WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(userHandle, () => { Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath, filePermissions });, where userHandle = aaa:shareabc, directoryPath = /shr/abc and filePermission = UnixFileMode.UserRead | UnixFileMode.UserWrite | ... | UnixFileMode.OtherRead | UnixFileMode.OtherExecute

Call seteuid, setegid, or run commands with sudo, or simply run chmod g+s /shr/abc. Check this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27305

Thanks.  Looks like there's no real nice solution to this.  I'll have to go with create then fix after for now until there's a nicer way to do it.  Reading that link, I can imagine setegid->mkdir will be worse than calling mkdir->chown due to implied race conditions when working concurrently across abc and def.
